# Strange TableView and SearchBar

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a very strange problem with my SearchBar and TableView.
I have a MapView with this SearchBar, you can search name of place in the searchbar and I filter the name with a database, if the name exists it will be added in the TableView.
I can search it without problem but I got two strange problem.
If I got 3-4 value in the TableView if I search a fifth value like, it will not be displayed.
The second problem that I have is that if I got similar place name and I Click on one of two if I try to research it for second time the tableview will display me only the name that I clicked before and if I try to click it for a third time and I try to research it , tableview will not show it.
(When I click on the value on the TableView it simple show me it on the map.)

Video of the bug: https://streamable.com/e72wn

Code:

```
extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    //print("updateSearchResults")

    // *When user open the Search Bar and he doesn't type text or the text is very short this code clean the TableView.*
    let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
    if searchText == nil || searchText!.isEmpty {
        seenNames.removeAll()
        matchingItems.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    guard let mapView = mapView else { return }

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText
    request.region = mapView.region
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

    search.start { response, _ in
        guard let response = response else {
            return
        }

        for (index , name) in response.mapItems.enumerated() {
            let item = response.mapItems[index]
            if(checkIfNameExistInDB(key: String(name.name!)) != nil && !seenNames.contains(name.name!)){
                matchingItems.append(item)
                seenNames.insert(name.name!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else {
                print(name.name!)
            }
        }
}
}
}
```

Code of TableView:

```
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
    cell.imageView?.image = imageWithImage(image: UIImage(named: "search_1x")!, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)
    return cell
}
```

After the bug with the first name the SearchBar looks like blocked and doesn't search nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is caused by the large number of request spawned while you type your search terms, because on each character typed or deleted a new MKLocalSearch is created and started.
To verify this, I put something like your code in a playground and tested:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit
import MapKit

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var searches = [MKLocalSearch]()

for i in 1...100 {
    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Via roma n. \(i), Roma"
    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { (response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("request \(i) finished with error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let _ = response else {
            print("request \(i) finished with no response")
            return
        }

        print("request \(i) completed successfully!")
    }
    searches.append(search)
}
```

You will see that some requests are completed without errors, and for some requests you'll get

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKErrorDomain error 3.)
```

Which is MKErrorLoadingThrottled. This error, according to [Apple dev](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkerrorcode/mkerrorloadingthrottled?language=occ), occurs when

> The data was not loaded because data throttling is in effect. This error can occur if an app makes frequent requests for data over a short period of time.

Furthermore according to [Apple dev](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/EnablingSearch/EnablingSearch.html):

> There are no request limits per app or developer ID, so well-written apps that operate correctly should experience no problems. However, throttling may occur in a poorly written app that creates extremely large numbers of requests.

So at the end, the solution to your problem could be delay the start of the search request until the user has finished typing (you can use a timer that fire when the user did not press any keyboard key for an amount of time.)

PS: VERY IMPORTANT is remember to cancel your previous request, before start a new one, otherwise you'll get unexpectable behaviours

Comment: Thanks for your time. Everytime that I put a new character it create a new response, in which way can I limit it?

Comment: Reed at the end of the answer

Comment: Yes, I have seen now the last part. What do you mean for ‘delete previously response’?

Comment: the most important part for your case is "So at the end, the solution to your problem could be delay the start of the search request until the user has finished typing (you can use a timer that fire when the user did not press any keyboard key for an amount of time.)"

Comment: I solved by myself rewriting all. Thanks for your time